# Rebuild all Solr indices script hangs

Tags: content-search

I have a piece of code that performs a full rebuild for all Solr cores (using Sitecore XP 9.1.1):

```
foreach (Sitecore.ContentSearch.ISearchIndex index in Sitecore.ContentSearch.ContentSearchManager.Indexes)
{   
    var job = Sitecore.ContentSearch.Maintenance.IndexCustodian.FullRebuild(index, true);
    while (!job.IsDone) {
       System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

All indices are built, but the script hangs after the last index is built.

Any clues what am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same problem and had to extend the SOLR Timeout like so:

```
        <setting name="ContentSearch.Solr.ConnectionTimeout">
            <patch:attribute name="value">500000</patch:attribute>
        </setting>
```

Comment: Seems to be a different problem, I have it already set to `<setting name="ContentSearch.Solr.ConnectionTimeout" value="600000">`

Comment: Did you have a look at the crawling logs ?

Comment: Yes, nothing special in the crawling logs; no errors there.